# Updating Subscriber's Email in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

If we use our Salesforce Contact ID as the Subscriberkey in Marketing Cloud and have an associated email which is subsequently blocked the Subscriber would not be included in future deployments. However, if we were to update the email address would the subscriber remain blocked or would they be unblocked due to the email field being updated?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume by blocked, you mean unsubscribed. If the customer is unsubscribed and you update the email address they will still remain unsubscribed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring the status of the subscriber to Unsubscribe?

Say if the status of ContactID 12345 with email address chdjdh@domain.com is unsubscribed. Now even if you update the email address for ContactID 12345, still the email won't be sent out. This is because the Marketing CLoud does not track the email address in this instance and will only track the SubscriberKey which is the ContactID.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Chandan. So if a Subscriber is hard bounced on an email associated with subscriberkey (contactID) 12345 and then updates their email via Preference centre will that email update be reflected on AllSubscribers so you're able to reach the Subscriber again?